# Mac-address identification through traceroute

Tags: layer2, cisco-commands, traceroute

i would like to know the command syntax to trace a mac address in a lan.
I'm experiencing some issue in quick localization of a device by using only that information,
I remember the use of 'traceroute mac-src mac-dst' command, and in particular to specify the same address as src and dst to locate a device in Cisco Catalyst devices, but I would need to know the command usage in Cisco Nexus and Huawei devices, and optionally I would need to know how the process to trace a layer-2 address works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While some switches offer some kind of MAC 'tracing', an actual traceroute functionality isn't possible due to the lack of a TTL field in Ethernet - see [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56750/is-it-possible-to-perform-a-layer-2-mac-address-traceroute) for details.

What you can do however, is check the switch's MAC table for both the source and the destination MAC address (depending on vendor/OS something along `show mac address-table` or `show mac-address`). The MAC table indicates on which ports those MAC addresses have last been visible and which VLANs they are associated with.